# Why was the 'const' keyword created in Java?

Tags: java, constants, keyword

I have noticed that there is the `const` keyword in Java. It reminded me of things like `static` and `final` variables there.

But why was it created without anyone actually using it?

Comment: @ItamarGreen People are using it how? It's a keyword, but it doesn't appear in the grammar. What are you talking about?

Comment: @JoeC *et al.* This is not a duplicate of that question. This one is about why the keyword exists, not why the feature doesn't exist.

Comment: This was a very, very early decision in the design of Java.  I suspect the designers wanted to leave their options open, in case they wished to add a `const` facility to Java in the future.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The reason is clearly stated in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9), and your suspicion does not form part of it.

Answer (score 10):

From the [JLS #3.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9):

> The keywords `const` and `goto` are reserved, even though they are not currently used. This may allow a Java compiler to produce better error messages if these C++ keywords incorrectly appear in programs.